# How to get a list of facebook groups for a user using graph api v.2.4?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Now graph api has version 2.4. I want to get a list of facebook groups for a user using graph api. I check user_managed_groups in user data permission already. But it return null.

How do I do?

Comment: Show us some code of what you have already tried and we'll be better equipped to help

Answer (score 0):

You probably don´t manage any groups, that´s why you don´t get anything with `/me/groups` and the `user_managed_groups` permission. You can only get a list of groups you manage. That´s all i can say, for more information you would need to extend your question with some details and example code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to get a list of all groups someone is a member of using Graph 2.4?

In version 2.4 this feature is deprecated unless you are an administrator of the group in question. You will just get an empty array returned - which is probably why you're seeing null.

Basically the functionality is no longer there for what you want.